# How is Pi antibonding orbital more polar than Pi bonding orbital?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, molecular-orbital-theory

While reading about the solvent effect on electronic transition in ESR spectroscopy, I found it written somewhere that the pi anti-bonding orbitals are more polar compared to pi bonding orbitals.

Can somebody explain how and why is it so?

Comment: I am also new to this theory, but I feel that $\displaystyle \pi ^*_{ABMO} $ has a nodal plane in between the nuclei of atoms, and also has greater energy than normal atomic orbital whereas   $\displaystyle \pi _{BMO} $ is of lower energy  and has maximum electron density between nuclei. Thus $\displaystyle \pi ^*_{ABMO} $ is more polar

Comment: We can also take into account, the high energy electronic repulsion in $\displaystyle \pi ^ *_{ABMO} $.